# iPhone Loading Screen Effect

Tags: iphone

I'm interested to making a "fade effect" like Foursquare app. I want the main view to fade in.

How can I do this?

---

Sincerely I don't know what should I use. If anyone have the Foursquare's app on his iPhone, please open and see what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at these answers:

[How can I display a splash screen for longer on an iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553336/how-can-i-display-a-splash-screen-for-longer-on-an-iphone)

This is what I've used in almost all of my apps:

http://iphoneinaction.manning.com/iphone_in_action/2009/05/creating-a-splash-screen-splashview-11.html

Answer (score 0):

Displaying a "splash screen" and using the "fade effect" are really two different questions. As for fading, UIView has a bunch of built-in animations you can use which is provided by Core Animation. Look into the UIView docs Apple provides for these type of view animation.

Answer (score 0):

The splash image is white with a fake nav controller on the top.

When the app finishes launching, the splash image is redisplay on top.

The typical UIView elements are added beneath the second splash image.

When this is finished, the second splash image transparency is animated to fully transparent and thus causes a "fade effect".

Comment: I mean the screen with "JOIN NOW" and "LOG IN". When it appears there is a "fade effect." Programmatically, how can I do this? Thanks dude.

Comment: Still the same.  Try this.  Add a button onto a UIView.  Then add another UIView with a white background that fills the entire screen.  The button is now hidden.  Next, write some code that animates transparency of the white background UIView all the way to fully transparent.