# How can I set the splash screen display time?

Tags: cocoa-touch, splash-screen

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I display a splash screen for longer on an iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553336/how-can-i-display-a-splash-screen-for-longer-on-an-iphone)

How can I set the splash screen display time?

Comment: Edited your title and tags. It's *not* Xcode. Xcode is the IDE that can be used to program a wide variety of things in a wide variety of languages. You mean either Cocoa (Mac OS X apps) or Cocoa Touch (iOS apps).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Read the Apple iPhone Human Interface Guidelines (HIG). The "splash screen" isn't supposed to be for branding or displaying a logo, it's supposed to look like the default condition of the app so it appears to start up quickly.

Making it stay there for longer would be a violation of the HIG.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/UEBestPractices/UEBestPractices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH20-SW1

iOS applications should start as quickly as possible so that people can begin using them without delay. When starting, iOS apps should:

Display a launch image that closely resembles the first screen of the application. This practice decreases the perceived launch time of your application.

Avoid displaying an About window or a splash screen. In general, try to avoid providing any type of startup experience that prevents people from using your application immediately.

Answer (score 4):

Add a UIImageView with your splash screen image to be the top view in your root view controller. Once the real splash is removed, this one will displayed seamlessly. You can then remove it after a set time or even add a nice effect such as fading or animating it out.

Answer (score 0):

add a picture in Resource file named Default.png. And in [xxx]AppDelegate.m write the following code:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)app {
    sleep(3); // sleep 3 second
        ....
}
```

That's everything you need to do

Comment: Do not do this. Forcing the main thread to sleep on `-applicationDidFinishLaunching:` is strongly discouraged. If this method takes too long to execute the app will be terminated.

Comment: +1 This is a fine solution if you don't mind using a quick and dirty hack.