# Is prolonging my Launchimage in order to allow map-tiles to load on main/initial app screen a bad practice? If yes, what is correct practice?

Tags: ios, mkmapview

[I've read that it is bad practice to prolong the launch image (splash image).](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553336/how-can-i-display-a-splash-screen-for-longer-on-an-iphone)

That being said, this seems like a moment when this is a smart thing to do: I'm loading to a mapview on launch and I keep seeing yet-to-be-loaded-tiles. I'd rather stay on my launchimage for another .5 seconds and load straight into the actual satellite imagery.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Having the launchimage alpha be conditional to the tiles being loaded would be optimal.

Answer (score 1):

Because the launch image is static it doesn't show the user that something useful is happening. You could get to the map view as soon as possible, but show a progress indicator over the blank area until the tiles have finished loading. Or add another view that looks just like the launch image with the twirling indicator on the top to show it is doing something, but I prefer the first version.