# How to display splash screen a little bit longer

Tags: ios, objective-c

I know this question has been asked and answered many times but i'm not sure where to put the code at the right place.

```
- (void) applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication*)application
{
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:5.0];
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12725105/1342266

Comment: under **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions** set `sleep(0.5);` 
change the float value as per you want

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Apps that don't launch in a timely manner can be rejected by Apple. Also, how does showing a splash screen they're not likely to care about serve the user?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a UIView containing your splash screen content and display it in the initial view controller. When you finish processing whatever you want to process, just hide this UIView or remove it totally.

Answer (score -1):

You have to put

```
[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:5.0]
```

in

```
 applicationDidFinishLaunching
```

method of `appDelegate.swift` file